# WeChat Oauth python

Tags: python, wechat

Tutorial about getting started with Wechat as an admin was implemented on php http://admin.wechat.com/wiki/index.php?title=Getting_Started . Tried doing something similar in python as:

```
import webapp2

class weChatAuth(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        message = self.request.GET['echostr']
        self.response.write(message)
```

Know quiet well that it may be not be the right approach. But how can I do something similar with python. BTW, i am hosting on google app engine.